# Oracle JDBC Client Net Trace

Tags: java, oracle, logging, jdbc

I'm interested in generating the Oracle network trace file using the Oracle JDBC thin client. In particular, I'm interested in the details of the network encryption negotiation and validating the specific algorithm being used for the connection.

From other Oracle clients, such as SQL*Plus, this is accomplished by updating the `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora` file with the following content:

```
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED=off
TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT=/tmp
TRACE_FILE_CLIENT=nettrace
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT=16
```

This produces a trace file that contains all the details I'm interested, e.g.

```
(2017502720) [09-MAR-2017 13:43:25:133] na_tns:     Authentication is not active
(2017502720) [09-MAR-2017 13:43:25:133] na_tns:     Encryption is active, using AES256
(2017502720) [09-MAR-2017 13:43:25:133] na_tns:     Crypto-checksumming is active, using SHA1
```

I'd like to accomplish the same thing from my Java application.

I've already enabled Oracle tracing in my app by doing the following:

- including the `ojdbc7_g.jar` on the classpath
- creating a `logging.properties` file with `oracle.level = ALL`
- specifying the following system properties: `-Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties`

This provides detailed Oracle jdbc logging, including some `oracle.net` log messages, but does not contain the same detailed content as the tracing configured in sqlnet.ora (specifically, for example, I can't see which encryption algorithm is being used).

How can I get this detailed net tracing from my Oracle JDBC application? Are there any corresponding thin client connection properties that can be provided to my `OracleDataSource` (I didn't notice any related `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection` constants, which is where I set some other properties that are typically specified in sqlnet.ora)?

Comment: If all you want to do is be sure that Encryption is enabled, you can use the getEncryptionAlgorithmName() method on OracleConnection. In the example you gave it would return "AES256".

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to get more detailed logging similar to what's provided in the network trace file (and without modifying code), but it's good to know that there is at least a method that can be invoked to get some of the data I'm interested in.

Comment: Unfortunately the JDBC thin driver doesn't provide this information in any logging. You can however turn on sqlnet tracing on the server-side.

Comment: Have you considered turning on sqlnet tracing on the server? This will produce the same output as what OCI produces on the client and will work for all connections including JDBC thin connections.

Comment: Access to the server is not always available. Further, my server may have many connections from different clients, and I'd only be interested in tracing for one client, not all clients.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old whitepaper, but maybe it is still possible to enable it for the thin client like this:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/11-2.pdf

[..]
Not all issues can be resolved by looking at the JDBC logging messages. For some it is helpful tolook at the network packets the driver exchanges with the server. The OCI C library has anetwork trace mode that provides this information. This is well documented and can be found in the OCI documentation. The Thin driver does not use the OCI C library so that does not help when you are using the Thin driver. Beginning with Oracle Database Release 11.2, the OracleJDBC Thin driver include a network trace capability. Like all other JDBC logging, it uses java.util.logging.In order to generate network level trace information add the following line to your config file:oracle.net.ns.level = FINEST
[..]